# Optimal SNAPLEN for PCAP live capture

Tags: c, live, pcap, snapshot, mtu

When using `pcap_open_live` to sniff from an interface, I have seen a lot of examples using various numbers as `SNAPLEN` value, ranging from `BUFSIZ` (`<stdio.h>`) to "magic numbers".

Wouldn't it make more sense to set as SNAPLEN the MTU of the interface we are capturing from ?
In this manner, we could fit more packets at once in PCAP buffer. Is it safe to assume that the MRU is equal to the MTU ?

Otherwise, is there a non-exotic way to set the SNAPLEN value ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The MTU is the largest *payload* size that could be handed to the link layer; it does not include any link-layer headers, so, for example, on Ethernet it would be 1500, not 1514 or 1518, and wouldn't be large enough to capture a full-sized Ethernet packet.

In addition, it doesn't include any metadata headers such as the radiotap header for 802.11 radio information.

And if the adapter is doing any form of fragmentation/segmentation/reassembly offloading, the packets handed to the adapter or received from the adapter might not yet be fragmented or segmented, or might have been reassembled, and, as such, might be *much* larger than the MTU.

As for fitting more packets in the PCAP buffer, that only applies to the memory-mapped TPACKET_V1 and TPACKET_V2 capture mechanisms in Linux, which have fixed-size packet slots; other capture mechanisms do not reserve a maximum-sized slot for every packet, so a shorter snapshot length won't matter.  For TPACKET_V1 and TPACKET_V2, a smaller snapshot length could make a difference, although, at least for Ethernet, libpcap 1.2.1 attempts, as best it can, to choose an appropriate buffer slot size for Ethernet.  (TPACKET_V3 doesn't appear to have the fixed-size per-packet slots, in which case it wouldn't have this problem, but it only appeared in officially-released kernels recently, and no support for it exists yet in libpcap.)

Comment: alright, so I have to "guess" a probable maximum size for the traffic I am going to monitor.

Comment: *If* you're using Linux with a modern version of libpcap, and either the version isn't 1.2.1 or later or you're not capturing on Ethernet (or are capturing on Ethernet with fragmentation/segmentation/reassembly offloading), *and* you don't want to allocate a huge shared-memory buffer (using `pcap_create()`/`pcap_set_buffer_size()`/`pcap_activate()`), and want to avoid packet drops, you'll have to guess a probable maximum size for packets delivered to libpcap.

Comment: Ok, my problem is twofold since I do not analyze each packet before getting the new one, hence I have to buffer also on user application level. That's why I am trying to trim on memory usage.

Comment: Then you either need to have a buffering scheme in your code that doesn't allocate maximum-packet-size buffers for all packets or you have to choose a "minimum sufficient" maximum packet size; the latter is tricky (which is why libpcap only attempts it for `TPACKET_V[12]` in some cases).